# Using db_query in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, database

I'm in the process of porting my contrib module from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7, and I'm getting a little stuck with how I should got about using db_query() in Drupal 7. I know it now uses a similar syntax to PDO, but I'm not quite sure how to translate the following line from the Drupal 6 version of the module:

```
if ($result = db_query('SELECT name FROM {variable} WHERE name LIKE "%%%s%"', 'csm_node_temp_')) {
while ($array = db_fetch_array($result)) {
  $variables[] = $array['name'];
}
```

}

This code removes all of the variables that my module has added to the variable table; i.e., all variables with names that start with the string "csm_node_temp". How should I rewrite these lines for the Drupal 7 version of my module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The D7 equivalent would be:

```
$sql = 'SELECT name FROM {variable} WHERE name LIKE :name';
$args = array(':name' => db_like('csm_node_temp_') . '%');

foreach (db_query($sql, $args) as $result) {
  $names[] = $result->name;
}
```

Or if you wanted a structured query using `db_select()`:

```
$variables = db_select('variable', 'v')
  ->fields('v', array('name'))
  ->condition('name', db_like('csm_node_temp_') . '%', 'LIKE');

foreach ($variables->execute() as $result) {
  $names[] = $result->name;
}
```

n.b. the above are the most basic use of either of those functions. With some of the helper methods they get a bit more powerful.

For example, you're just looking for a single column of data from your query. The DB API can handle this with the `fetchCol()` method. So for the first example you can do:

```
$sql = 'SELECT name FROM {variable} WHERE name LIKE :name';
$args = array(':name' => db_like('csm_node_temp_') . '%');
$names = db_query($sql, $args)->fetchCol();
```

and for the second:

```
$names = db_select('variable', 'v')
  ->fields('v', array('name'))
  ->condition('name', db_like('csm_node_temp_') . '%', 'LIKE')
  ->execute()
  ->fetchCol();
```

In both cases `$names` will contain an array of the names found by the query. Much easier than looping over the results manually :)

Comment: I was just writing a comment saying I believe the syntax will still work with D7. D7 added support for named parameters, but as far as I'm aware, doesn't require them. That said, named parameters are easier to read and less error prone because their ordering doesn't matter, so your example is still preferred IMO. (And for something as simple as this, I would think a db_select is overkill, no?)

Comment: @Letharion Try running `db_query("SELECT * FROM {users} WHERE uid = %d", array(1))` through `db_query()` in Drupal 7. It'll break nicely :) You can't use the `%` placeholders in D7 queries, they're just not catered for

Comment: @Letharion Yeah `db_select()` is overkill for such a simple query, but the OP's just coming over from D6 so I think it's good for him to know the dynamic option too

Comment: You are right of course, it's because one can use ? for unnamed parameters that I just assumed the syntax remained the same.

Comment: Thanks! As there will be likely be more than one result, would $name[] = $result->name be better in the first example, and similar in the second example?

Comment: @Jim, looks like it yes. Just a small oversight by Clive I believe.

Comment: @Jim Yep, I just put that line in as an example it wasn't supposed to match exactly. I've updated the answer with a better solution though...